# architecture question in asp.net core 3 - handle existing code with static call

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

I actually rewrite a Silverlight app in blazor, and I met some problem with reusing ViewModels from the Silverlight app in my app.

The existing ViewModels use a lot of a static access as a repository, session-like system. In client-side version of blazor, it will not be a problem normally, but on the server side it's obviously a big problem, all clients will shared same repository which is not OK.

For the moment I develop only in server side, I need debugging to develop correctly. For the target, we actually don't know if we will use the client or server version, but we want keep possibility to use both.

Refactoring the existing ViewModels is a complicated task because the existing app depend of them and it will be a huge and complicated refactoring, including potential regression on the actual app. I can rewrite the entry point of the static class if needed but I can't really replace the calls to the static everywhere.

So the question, there is any way to manage a static class to "retrieve" for example an session-scoped service

1 - something like that

```
//this is the existing repository class, I can rewrite it, but calls like Locator.UiParameter need stay valid
public static class Locator
{
    public static UiParameterViewModel UiParameter
    {
        get
        {
            UiParameterService myScopedService = ?????;
            return myScopedService.UiParameter;
        }
    }
}
```

2 - If I can't, it is possible with a singleton system ? (and I replace all calls to Locator by Locator.Instance for example?

Comment: It is not possible make that work, if you want to use 'scoped' service. Since at the same time you can have more then one scoped service in the memory. Single static class does not have a way to distinguish which instance to use.

Comment: You better start creating of new class which would be not singleton, and can be injected into the View models. That way you could rewrite view models one by one